# How can I use a recursive CTE in Mysql 8 to get dated, hierarchical information from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression, mysql-8.0

Normally, this wouldn't be too hard. I could just use a few normal joins or subqueries and get the data. However, what complicates it is that I have to be able to get the data based on a specific date. I would usually grab that with ORDER BY DESC and LIMIT 1. But you can't do that on a recursive CTE in Mysql 8. An employee's promotion level as well as their parent id are in two separate tables and have a start date. So I need to be able to get the information given a specific date. I have created a fiddle with some sample data and the query I have so far. I think at the moment, my query is creating a recursion error.

The desired result would be, given user id 3, to get a table with data for user 3 and all of their "children".

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oTDa9TZFY9eNx1voRjSXsa/2

As suggested, below is some sample data and the query I am working on in case the fiddle disappears:

```
    CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `firstname` VARCHAR(100),
    `lastname` VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname)
VALUES
    ('John', 'Doe'),
    ('Jane', 'Doe'),
    ('Bob', 'Smith'),
    ('Alice', 'Smith'),
    ('Tom', 'Jones'),
    ('Mary', 'Johnson'),
    ('David', 'Brown'),
    ('Karen', 'Davis'),
    ('Richard', 'Miller'),
    ('Susan', 'Wilson'),
    ('Paul', 'Moore'),
    ('Betty', 'Taylor'),
    ('George', 'Anderson'),
    ('Lisa', 'Thomas'),
    ('Kenneth', 'Jackson'),
    ('Angela', 'White'),
    ('Steven', 'Harris'),
    ('Ruth', 'Martin'),
    ('Brian', 'Thompson'),
    ('Dorothy', 'Young');


CREATE TABLE `user_parent` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `parent_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `start_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO user_parent (user_id, parent_id, start_date)
VALUES
    (1, 2, '2020-01-02'),
    (1, 3, '2021-06-22'),
    (3, 4, '2022-05-08'),
    (4, 3, '2020-11-23'),
    (5, 3, '2021-08-19'),
    (6, 3, '2023-03-28'),
    (7, 4, '2022-07-12'),
    (7, 5, '2021-10-31'),
    (9, 10, '2020-09-11'),
    (10, 11, '2022-02-14'),
    (11, 12, '2021-03-17'),
    (12, 13, '2023-06-28'),
    (13, 5, '2020-08-27'),
    (14, 5, '2021-01-30'),
    (15, 5, '2022-04-05'),
    (16, 13,'2023-07-18'),
    (17 ,15,'2020-06-16'),
    (18 ,15,'2022-01-25'),
    (19 ,20,'2021-02-28'),
    (20 ,1,'2023-05-09');
    
 CREATE TABLE `user_levels` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `user_level` INT NOT NULL,
    `start_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO user_levels (user_id, user_level, start_date)
VALUES
    (1, 100, '2020-01-02'),
    (2, 200, '2021-06-22'),
    (3, 400, '2021-01-01'),
    (3, 500, '2022-05-08'),
    (4, 400, '2020-11-23'),
    (5, 500, '2021-08-19'),
    (6, 100, '2023-03-28'),
    (7, 200, '2022-07-12'),
    (8, 300, '2021-10-31'),
    (9, 400, '2020-09-11'),
    (10, 500, '2022-02-14'),
    (11, 100, '2021-03-17'),
    (12, 200, '2023-06-28'),
    (13, 300, '2020-08-27'),
    (14, 400, '2021-01-30'),
    (15, 300,'2021-02-05'),
    (15, 500,'2022-04-05'),
    (16 ,100,'2023-07-18'),
    (17 ,200,'2020-06-16'),
    (18 ,300,'2022-01-25'),
    (19 ,400,'2021-02-28'),
    (20 ,500,'2023-05-09');


WITH RECURSIVE cte (id,firstname,lastname,user_level,parent_id,start_date,depth) AS (
                SELECT u.id,u.firstname,u.lastname,(SELECT user_level FROM user_levels WHERE user_id = 3 AND start_date <= '2023-08-25' ORDER BY start_date DESC LIMIT 1),0 as parent_id,'2023-08-22' as start_date,0 as depth
                    FROM users u
                    WHERE u.id=3
                    
                UNION ALL
                
                SELECT u.id,u.firstname,u.lastname,(SELECT user_level FROM user_levels WHERE user_id = u.id AND start_date <= '2023-08-25' ORDER BY start_date DESC LIMIT 1) as level_code,up.parent_id,up.start_date,cte.depth+1
                FROM users u,cte
                INNER JOIN LATERAL
                (SELECT user_id, parent_id, MAX(start_date) as start_date
                    FROM user_parent p
                    WHERE p.parent_id = cte.id AND p.start_date <= '2023-08-25' GROUP BY p.user_id)
                AS up
                )
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

Comment: Thanks for adding a fiddle to your question but please add the contents of it to your question. Fiddle links are temporary hence at some point this question will be useless to other people visiting the site!

Comment: Also it would be helpful to have the desired result based on the fiddle data.

Comment: Good ideas. Updated my question to reflect them.